# TypeError: agent.intent is not a function at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to display the few items using actions-on-google Carousel, to handle the click action I need to use intent('actions.intent.OPTION', (?,?,?)) function, but doing it results in below error,

```
ERROR:

TypeError: agent.intent is not a function at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest
```

The code is

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {
    WebhookClient
} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {
    Image,
    Carousel,
    BrowseCarousel,
    BrowseCarouselItem,
} = require('actions-on-google');
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({
    request,
    response
  });
  agent.requestSource = agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE;
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('video.search', searchQuery);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

  agent.action('actions.intent.OPTION', (conv, params, option) => {
    let response = 'You did not select any item';
    if (option) {
        response = 'You have chosen: ' + option;
    }
    conv.ask(response);
  });
}
```

Kindly help If I'm missing anything in here ?

Also, I need to trigger the deep link, from the intent handled method is there any way to trigger explicit deep link intent URI from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems odd, but it looks like you copied the code from Google's documentation without reading the rest of the info, and have tried changing it to `agent.action`.

The problem is that you are treating `agent.action` as a function - and it is not. [This is a property](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client#webhookclientaction_string) that contains the name of the "action" that was set in the Parameters section for the Intent.

Handling `actions.intent.OPTION` through Dialogflow is by creating an Intent that has the *event* `actions_intent_OPTION` with no training phrases. Something like this:

[image]

You would then have a handler that handles the "input.option" intent (to use the name I did in the example), just as you would for other intent handlers.

Comment: Hi @Prisoner, Thank you very much it worked by creating the intent with the "actions_intent_OPTION". My apologies I am new to dialog flow for missing this I couldn't find the difference between intent method and property.

Comment: Can you please also provide some example for handling the event. I want to link content from carousel to an external app or fallback website through an http deeplink url.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a deeplink URL. It sounds like you may wish to ask a new StackOverflow question with details about what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what isn't working.